# Estimating the confidence interval for each half of a population

Tags: confidence-interval, population

We are looking at how a change in the environment (confinement level) alters which of two behaviors our model organism chooses. We perform several trials at each confinement level. Each of these trials elicits one of the two possible behaviors. From this we get a fraction of trials which exhibited each behavior under each of the environmental conditions. I want to calculate the confidence interval for each of the fraction estimates under each environmental condition.

So an example would be at a confinement level of 10 (on some arbitrary scale) behavior one is used in 23 of 31 trials, and behavior two is used in the other 8.

My guess is that the proper thing to do it to use r's 1−sample proportions test with alternate k values for each pair of fractions (as in: http://www.r-tutor.com/elementary-statistics/interval-estimation/interval-estimate-population-proportion). So for our example, prop.test(23, 31) and prop.test(8, 31) giving confidence intervals of (0.55,0.87) and (0.12, 0.44). Or is there some reason not to use a 1-sample proportion test on each member of the fraction pair? If the answer is just, "nope, that's fine", well... great!